# How to dynamically search/replace text with update in XQuery (exist-db)

Tags: xquery, exist-db

My intention is to somehow clean source files automatically. How to do that in XQuery? (I am not interested in reconstructing the document in memory and storing it as a new one.) It is quite easy to do something similar in case of short and simple elements addressed directly, however, I can’t figure out how to do that dynamically for all the text nodes, if possible.

I would expect something like this could work:

```
update replace $div[contains(., 'chapter')] with replace(., 'chapter', 'Chapter')
```

This throws `err:XPDY0002 Undefined context sequence for 'self::node()' [source: String]`

Apparently, there is a problem in addressing the context with `.` in the replacing function. But maybe I don’t understand the `update` thing in general. I am only inspired by the bottom of [this article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Updates_and_Namespaces).

Comment: Replace the 2nd `.` with `$div` ?

Comment: It seems it works, funny as always! If you can, please, post the answer, I will confirm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression to the right of `with` is independent from expression to the left. So an explicit node/context is needed on both part :

```
update replace $div[contains(., 'chapter')] with replace($div, 'chapter', 'Chapter')
```